# Excel: Use of spaces in filenames/sheetnames with INDIRECT()

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

Formula is:
`=INDIRECT("'Z:\ADMIN PROJECTS\[FORWARD ORDERS.xlsx]"&A1&"'!C$2")`

Value of A1 is SEPT 13 in text (to be replaced by another formula soon).

Excel keeps giving me #REF. I'm pretty sure INDIRECT is not happy with my use of spaces, but they need to be there for usability.

Help!

Comment: Hmm, I'm pretty sure it's due to the fact that `INDIRECT` doesn't work on closed files. I'm not sure about a workaround, but even without spaces, I get the same error if the file is closed. To confirm, try opening the file `FORWARD ORDERS.xlsx`, then open the workbook containing the indirect formula. It worked if I did that.

Comment: @Jerry Dammit you're right. Crapola. I need to rethink my strategy or manually edit every sheet. Shoot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/151323

`The INDIRECT function will only return the result of a reference to an open file. If a workbook that the INDIRECT function is indirectly referencing is closed (not open in memory) the function will return a #REF! error.`

3rd party plugins like PULL and INDIRECT.EXT have been written to get around the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Indirect() only works with open files. The free [Morefunc.xll](http://download.cnet.com/Morefunc/3000-2077_4-10423159.html) add-in has a function called Indirect.Ext which also works with closed files.

Caveat: Morefunc was developed a while ago and may not work with more recent Excel versions.